# Spring batch FTP file

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using *Spring Batch ItemReader* to read data from a database and then using *FlatFileItemWriter* to write the data to a file.

Once the data is written to a file, I need this specific file to be transferred to an FTP server. Can I do this via *Spring Batch* or should I use *Spring Integration*?  Could you please also provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in combining both frameworks. They really work together smoothly.

Since you say that you already have a Spring Batch `ItemReader` and your OK writing into a file using `FlatFileItemWriter`, so you are have way out for your whole solution.

In the end you can use a *Providing Feedback with Informational Messages* to get a file and send it to FTP using Spring Integration FTP Outbound Channel adapter.

See more info in Spring Batch Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#providing-feedback-with-informational-messages

And in Spring Integration about FTP support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#ftp